Recursive functions in R to apply regex within nested parentheses
I'm working with nested expressions in R and need some help with writing a recursive function to process these expressions starting with the innermost parentheses first.
Given a string like:
expr <- "(((a OR b) OR c) AND d) OR (e AND f)"

I want to perform the following replacements:

Replace all occurrences of "(i OR j)" with "min(1, i + j)"
Replace all occurrences of "(i AND j)" with "(i * j)"

For example:

"(a OR b)" should become "min(1, a + b)"
"(e AND f)" should become "(e * f)"

The string "((a OR b) OR c) AND d) OR (e AND f)" should evaluate to:
"min(1, (min(1, min(1, a + b) + c) * d) + (e * f))"
The challenge is that the expressions can be nested, and I need to handle the innermost parentheses first before moving outward. This is because I am writing functions to take user input for objective functions, and I have R code to dynamically write Rcpp code...
I've considered using regular expressions to find and replace the patterns, but handling the nested structures recursively is where I'm stuck. I've tried a recursive function approach the following:

process_expr <- function(string) {
  
  # Match the innermost parentheses
  pattern <- "\\(([^()]*)\\)"
  brackets <- gregexpr(pattern, string, perl = TRUE)
  matches <- regmatches(string, brackets)
  
  # If there are no more matches, return the string
  if (length(matches[[1]]) == 0) {
    return(string)
  }
  
  # Process each match
  for (match in matches[[1]]) {
    # Apply the replacements
    modified <- gsub("\\(([^()]+) OR ([^()]+)\\)", "min(1, \\1 + \\2)", match)
    modified <- gsub("\\(([^()]+) AND ([^()]+)\\)", "(\\1 * \\2)", modified)
    
    # Replace the match in the original string
    string <- sub(pattern, modified, string, fixed = TRUE)
  }
  
  # Recurse to process the next level of nested parentheses
  return(process_expr(string))
}

# Example usage
expr <- "((a OR b) OR c) AND d) OR (e AND f)"
result <- process_expr(expr)
print(result)

The code above doesn't seem to correctly handle the nested parentheses, especially when there are multiple levels of nesting. I need the function to:

Identify the innermost expressions first.
Apply the replacements correctly.
Handle multiple levels of nested expressions.

All the solutions I've looked at work for Python or Perl, but not for R.
Is there another approach that I can use to get what I need? i.e.,

Replace all occurrences of "(i OR j)" with "min(1, i + j)"
Replace all occurrences of "(i AND j)" with "(i * j)"

Example data: "(((a OR b) OR c) AND d) OR (e AND f)"
Needs to evaluate to:
min(1, (min(1, min(1, a + b) + c) * d) + (e * f))
EDIT:
Here are a couple of other I/O examples:
input_2 <- "(r1 && r2) || r3 + r4 + (r5 && r6)"

output_2:
"min(1, (r1 * r2) + r3) + r4) + (r6 * r7)"
Here are a couple of other I/O examples:
input_3 <- "(r1 && r2) || (r3 && r4) + r5 || (r6 + r7)"

output_3:
"min(1, (r1 * r2) + (r3 * r4)) + min(1, r5 + (r6 + r7))"

The main edge case that I can't figure out now is:
string <- "(a AND b) OR (c AND d) + e"
Needs to evaluate to "min(1, (a * b) + c * d)) + e" but none of the solutions/answers below (yet at time of writing) parse the expression like this, because they need to start with the innermost brackets first.

The output for the second example is not right. Note that + takes precedence over || thus  (r1 && r2)|| r3 + r4 + (r5 && r6) is structurally similar to  (r1 && r2)|| (r3 + r4 + (r5 && r6)).

If we translate the input to valid R code, we can use the parse and to the substitution. For example this helper function does the trick
transform <- function(expr) {
  tx <- function(e) {
    if (is.call(e)) {
      parts <- as.list(e)
      if (parts[[1]] == quote(`%OR%`)) {
        parts[[1]] <- quote(`min`)
        parts[[3]] <- bquote(.(tx(parts[[2]])) + .(tx(parts[[3]])))
        parts[[2]] <- 1
        as.call(parts)         
      } else if (parts[[1]]==quote(`%AND%`)) {
        parts[[1]] <- quote(`*`)
        parts[[2]] <- tx(parts[[2]])
        parts[[3]] <- tx(parts[[3]])
        as.call(parts)
      } else {
        parts[-1] <- lapply(parts[-1], tx)
        as.call(parts)
      }
    } else {
      e
    }
  }
  fix <- gsub("\\bOR\\b", "%OR%", gsub("\\bAND\\b", "%AND%", expr))
  fix <- gsub("\\|\\|", "%OR%", gsub("\\&\\&", "%AND%", fix))
  deparse1(tx(str2lang(fix)))
}

Which we can test with
expr <- "(((a OR b) OR c) AND d) OR (e AND f)"
transform(expr)
# [1] "min(1, ((min(1, (min(1, a + b)) + c)) * d) + (e * f))"
input_2 <- "(r1 && r2) || r3 + r4 + (r5 && r6)"
transform(input_2)
# [1] "min(1, (r1 * r2) + r3) + r4 + (r5 * r6)"
input_3 <- "(r1 && r2) || (r3 && r4) + r5 || (r6 + r7)"
transform(input_3)
# [1] "min(1, (r1 * r2) + (r3 * r4)) + min(1, r5 + (r6 + r7))"

We turn OR and AND into %OR% and %AND% which can be parsed by R and then walk the abstract syntax tree and do the transformation. The parse does the hard work of building the tree.

Amazing this is a neat solution thank you. This works great for the first input example. I am not sure why it doesn't work for input_2 and input_3?

@statneutrino Well, before you had just two operators with a clear order of operations/precedence. Not you seem to want to have the addition operator have a higher precedence than the and/or. In this case I swapped the other operators to functions with lower precedence.

Amazing thank you so much! I've been pulling my hair out for hours trying to figure this out. Thank you!

Op is  breaking rules of math. Note that + takes precedence over || thus  (r1 && r2)|| r3 + r4 + (r5 && r6) is structurally similar to  (r1 && r2)|| (r3 + r4 + (r5 && r6)).

@Onyambu But the OP doesn't claim to be using traditional rules of mathematics. A parser can turn arbitrary tokens into what ever syntax you want. As long as it's well defined and consistent, you should be fine. Precedence rules can vary by language.

I would transform the text into parseable R code, parse, recurse through the resulting call, then deparse:
(s0 <- "(((a OR b) OR c) AND d) OR (e AND f)")
## [1] "(((a OR b) OR c) AND d) OR (e AND f)"
(s1 <- gsub(" OR ", " | ", gsub(" AND ", " & ", s0)))
## [1] "(((a | b) | c) & d) | (e & f)"

recurse <- function(x) {
    if (!is.call(x))
        x
    else if ((n <- length(x)) == 3L) {
        if (identical(x[[1L]], quote(`|`)))
            call("min", 1, call("+", Recall(x[[2L]]), Recall(x[[3L]])))
        else if (identical(x[[1L]], quote(`&`)))
            call("*", Recall(x[[2L]]), Recall(x[[3L]]))
        else x
    }
    else {
        if (n >= 2L) for (i in 2L:n) x[[i]] <- Recall(x[[i]])
        x
    }    
}

(s2 <- deparse(recurse(str2lang(s1))))
## [1] "min(1, ((min(1, (min(1, a + b)) + c)) * d) + (e * f))"


Oops, I was too slow - this answer is structurally identical to an earlier one, but it uses non-trivially different code, so maybe I should leave it up ... ?

string_parse <- function(x){
  if(is.call(x)){
    if(x[[1]] == '|') x <-  call('min', 1, call('+', x[[2]], x[[3]]))
    else if(x[[1]] == '&') x[[1]] <- as.name('*')
    x[-1] <- lapply(x[-1], string_parse)
  }
  x
}

string <- "(((a OR b) OR c) AND d) OR (e AND f)"

string_parse(str2lang(gsub("AND", "&", gsub("OR", "|", string))))
min(1, ((min(1, (min(1, a + b)) + c)) * d) + (e * f))


An attempt using string substitution:
string <- "(((a OR b) OR c) AND d) OR (e AND f)"

# function to substitute a single expression
process_expression <- function(expression) {
  # check if expression is something OR something, or something AND something, with optional parentheses
  if(grepl("^[^()]+\\s+(?:OR|AND)\\s+[^()]+$", expression) || grepl("^\\([^()]+\\s+(?:OR)|(?:AND)\\s+[^()]+\\)$", expression)) {
    # convert to required output, using braces {} to avoid clashes with the () in string
    result <- gsub("\\(?([^()]+)\\s+OR\\s+([^()]+)\\)?", "min{1, \\1 + \\2}", expression)
    result <- gsub("\\(?([^()]+)\\s+AND\\s+([^()]+)\\)?", "{\\1 * \\2}", result)
  } else {
    stop("Invalid expression")
  }
  return(result)
}

# function to find and replace all expressions in a string
process_string <- function(string) {
  # find the (innermost) expressions
  match_data <- gregexpr("\\(?[^()]+\\s+(?:OR|AND)\\s+[^()]+\\)?", string)
  # get the match strings
  matches <- regmatches(string, match_data)[[1]]
  # substitute the matches for their processed equivalents
  result <- Reduce(\(s, m) gsub(m, process_expression(m), s, fixed = TRUE), matches, init=string)
  # recurse if any AND or OR remain
  if(grepl("(AND|OR)", result)) {
    result <- process_string(result)
  }
  # change braces back to parentheses
  result <- gsub("{", "(", gsub("}", ")", result, fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE)
  
  return(result)
}

process_string(string)
#> [1] "min(1, (min(1, min(1, a + b) + c) * d) + (e * f))"

Created on 2024-06-24 with reprex v2.1.0

Do you need the OR condition to necessarily evaluate to 1 if TRUE? Or in other words, would it be okay if (A OR B) evaluates to 2 (which would still be a TRUE in a logical sense) in those cases where both A and B are TRUE? If so, a very simple solution would be the following:
gsub(" +AND +"," * ",gsub(" +OR +"," + ",expr))

Note that this also takes care of any extra white space you may have accidentally added surrounding the OR/AND expressions.
EDIT: Also, as mentioned by another user in a comment below your question, you are missing one parenthesis at the beginning of expr.

Thanks very much for your answer. Yes unfortunately I require the answer to be 1 or the sum. Although I have just realised, maybe I could just divide by 2?

That's too bad, and I'm afraid if you divide by 2 you will unfortunately run into the same issue when only one of A or B are TRUE, since then your result will be 0.5 (plus the above expression will not be as simple).
